# Arduino String Formatting Issue

Tags: c, string, format, arduino

I'm making an Arduino-powered clock, and in the process, I'm trying to format integers into two-digit formatted strings for the time read-out (e.g. 1 into "01").

The following gives me "error: expected primary-expression before '{' token":

```
char * formatTimeDigits (int num) {
  char strOut[3] = "00";
  if (num < 10) {
    strOut = {'0', char(num)};
  }
  else {
    strOut = char(num);
  }
  return strOut;
}
```

I'm trying to use it as follows:

```
void serialOutput12() {
  printWeekday(weekday); // picks the right word to print for the weekday
  Serial.print(", "); // a comma after the weekday
  Serial.print(hour12, DEC); // the hour, sent to the screen in decimal format
  Serial.print(":"); // a colon between the hour and the minute
  Serial.print(formatTimeDigits(minute)); // the minute
  Serial.print(":"); // a colon between the minute and the second
  Serial.print(formatTimeDigits(second)); // the second
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The curly-brace syntax is valid for initial declaration of a variable, but not for assignment after the fact.

Also, you are returning a pointer to an automatic variable, which is no longer validly allocated once returned (and will be smashed by the next call, such as to `print`).  You need to do something like this:

```
void formatTimeDigits(char strOut[3], int num)
{
  strOut[0] = '0' + (num / 10);
  strOut[1] = '0' + (num % 10);
  strOut[2] = '\0';
}

void serialOutput12()
{
  char strOut[3]; // the allocation is in this stack frame, not formatTimeDigits

  printWeekday(weekday); // picks the right word to print for the weekday

  Serial.print(", "); // a comma after the weekday

  Serial.print(hour12, DEC); // the hour, sent to the screen in decimal format

  Serial.print(":"); // a colon between the hour and the minute

  formatTimeDigits(strOut, minute);
  Serial.print(strOut); // the minute

  Serial.print(":"); // a colon between the minute and the second

  formatTimeDigits(strOut, second);
  Serial.print(strOut); // the second
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks!

Being used to C#, I guess I assumed it'd be passing a reference to the function (eek).

Comment: It (your orignal example) *does* return a reference, but to an object that ceases to exist after the function exits (so it becomes a dangling reference).  C doesn't have in-built reference-counting / garbage-collection.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't directly set an array's contents with the `=` assignment operator (you can *initialise* an array, but that's a different thing, even though it looks similar).

Additionally:

- It doesn't sound like the Wiring `char(value)` function/operator does what you want; and
- If you want to return a pointer to that `strOut` array, you will have to make it have static storage duration.

The simple way to do what you want is `sprintf`:

```
char * formatTimeDigits (int num)
{
  static char strOut[3];

  if (num >= 0 && num < 100) {
    sprintf(strOut, "%02d", num);
  } else {
    strcpy(strOut, "XX");
  }

  return strOut;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `sprintf` is part of the Arduino library -- the libs are brutally subsetted to fit in a 14kb maximum text segment size.

Comment: Jeffrey Hantin: I've seen some examples that imply that it is, but doesn't have floating point support linked by default.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- You cannot assign to an array: `strOut = {'0', (char)num};`
- You return the address of an object that will cease to exist right after the return statement.

For the first problem, assign to array elements:

```
strOut[0] = '0';
strOut[1] = num;
strOut[2] = '\0';
```

For the 2nd problem, the solution is a bit more complicated. The best would be to pass a destination string to the `FormatTimeDigits()` function and let the caller worry about it.

```
FormatTimeDigits(char *destination, int num); /* prototype */
FormatTimeDigits(char *destination, size_t size, int num); /* or another prototype */
```

---

Still another point on the 1st item: you may have seen something similiar in an **initialization**. That's different than assignment, and it allows a similar looking construct as assignment.

```
char strOut[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}; /* ok, initialization */
strOut = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}; /* wrong, cannot assign to array */
```

Comment: Yeah, I had adapted the bracket syntax from an initialization I saw in a sample.  Is there any way to assign multiple values in an array in one statement?

Comment: There is no way to assign multiple array elements in one "simple" statement. But, as you're dealing with strings, you can use string functions, as in `strcpy(strOut, "00");` or `strcat(strOut, "00");` or `sprintf` ...